# how to implement loading progress bar in angularjs for multiple http request

Tags: jquery, angularjs

i want to implement progress bar for each page which will show me how much page have been loaded. i think it can be achieved with http interceptor but dont know how actually it will be  done.i know how interceptors works but i dont know how it will works for loading progress bar

i saw some online plugins but these plugins don't work every time, sometimes it skip showing loading bar for consecutive 5-7 hits of api

plugins:---http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/#

Comment: look for http interceptor in angularjs

Comment: @SyedAmirHussain  please read my question again

Comment: are you looking for how-to implement this in your application? I have implemented `angular-loading-bar` in my app to so loading screen for any http call.

Comment: i have used above mentioned loading bar but it is not consistent from every page sometime it appears most of time it doesn't

Comment: If you can share your code I may help you..